# Нужен ли CMS сайту?

Tags: php, база-данных, битрикс, cms

Создаю сайт-каталог для магазина, можно сказать, что уже заканчиваю. Сейчас на этапе создания страницы товара, где будет полное описание о товаре,  его характеристики. Столкнулся с проблемой вывода характеристик, товаров много разных (компьютерный магазин), т.е. у видеокарт одни характеристики, а у мониторов другие. Начал искать информацию о выводе характеристик, но все ролики показывали только как это сделать в Битриксе и др. Нужен ли CMS, можно ли обойтись без него, можно ли добавить CMS к уже готовому сайту?

Comment: А как у вас происходит добавление товаров, например, разделов и т д? Какая то самописная админка сделана или что?

Comment: @IlyaYaremchuk админки пока не делал, пока добавляю просто через phpMyAdmin

Comment: Ну тогда думай над структурой, как лучше и как ты будешь хранить характеристики, и выводи на страничку товара и куда там еще нужно (фильтр например)

Comment: @IlyaYaremchuk есть примеры?

Comment: Странно что изначально не была выбрана CMS

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov не знал ничего о CMS...  Подскажите, можно ли использовать CMS только для админки (добавлении товаров)

Comment: Теоретически да, но практически скорее нет, т.к. это будут огромные трудозатраты. Представьте что нужно будет или менять вашу БД под модели CMS, или менять сами модели под вашу БД и это при условиях что в контроллеры лезть не нужно будет.  Вариантов у вас 2 - или написать админку самому, или спарсить имеющиеся товары и импортировать в CMS (с этим могу помочь) ну и шаблон натянуть. Увы, но сейчас Вы по сути собираете сами велосипед, хотя получили какой то практический опыт.

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov на данном этапе лучше попробую написать админку сам, вреда от этого не будет, я думаю.

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov а вообще сейчас большинство сайтов, я так понимаю, пишутся на CMS? Поэтому нужно учится владеть и ими?

Comment: Вреда не будет 100%, но вопрос в том - шашечки или ехать. Т.е. есть ли у Вас лимит по времени или нет.

Comment: Именно владеть CMS особой сложности нету - само предназначение CMS это управление контентом без особых технических скиллов, т.е. добавление товаров происходит не через phpmyadmin, а через интуитивную панель, например для магазина - http://simplacms.ru/.  Основной момент - сколько можно сэкономить времени при установке и адаптировании CMS под себя. Но когда это невыгодно - то не пишут на голом PHP, а используют фреймворки.

Comment: А как сейчас-то реализовано хранение видеокарт и мониторов? Неужели в разных таблицах типа shop_graphic_cards / shop_displays?
Тогда у вас будут серьезные проблемы при поддержке

Comment: @Andrewus нет, все товары в одной таблице, просто у всех товаров есть тип

Comment: @ArsenTatraev у вас должно быть 4 таблицы - Товары, Категории, Характеристики (считай группы) и их Значения. Товары крепятся к Категориям, у которых индивидуальный набор Характеристик, с кучей Значений. Потом в каждом Товаре просто будете тыкать по Значениям, набирая нужные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMS просто экономят ваше время на разработку подобного функционала (в этом случае торговых предложений) + 
дают удобный UI для контентщиков, но за это иногда, как битрикс, требуют денег